# Open Telemetry makes Next.js initialization extremely slow

Tags: javascript, node.js, open-telemetry

When initializing Nextjs via `node -r` and `node --require` the application takes 4-5 minutes to load. The telemetry script loads within the first 5 seconds so this issue is likely related to Nextjs or node. This contrasts calling without node require module's 30 second load time.

Without node require module:

```
"dev": "env-cmd -f environments/.env.development next dev",
```

With node require module:

```
"dev": "env-cmd -f environments/.env.development node --require ./tracing.js ./node_modules/next/dist/bin/next dev",
```

This implementation is based on [ross-hagan's blog about instrument-nextjs-opentelemetry](https://ross-hagan.com/blog/instrument-nextjs-opentelemetry)

> Alternative to a custom server
>
> I originally started off with a completely separate tracing.js script
> with the contents of our start.js script without the startServer call.
>
> This separates the telemetry SDK startup from the server. You can then
> keep the Next.js built-in startup behaviours by using the node
> --require (-r) to load in a module before starting the Next app.
>
> In your npm run dev script in your package.json this looks like:
>
> node -r tracing.js ./node_modules/.bin/next dev
>
> I switched away from this after frustration getting the node command
> to run in a Dockerfile as this was destined for a Google Kubernetes
> Engine runtime. Also, some concern about use of the --require flag.
>
> See if it works for you to do it this way, as a Next.js custom server
> comes with some consequences documented in their docs!

---

I've tried two separate `tracing.js` without success in reducing load times.

`tracing.js` provided by open telemetry:

```
/* tracing.js */

// Require dependencies
const opentelemetry = require("@opentelemetry/sdk-node");
const { getNodeAutoInstrumentations } = require("@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node");
const { diag, DiagConsoleLogger, DiagLogLevel } = require('@opentelemetry/api');

// For troubleshooting, set the log level to DiagLogLevel.DEBUG
diag.setLogger(new DiagConsoleLogger(), DiagLogLevel.INFO);

const sdk = new opentelemetry.NodeSDK({
  traceExporter: new opentelemetry.tracing.ConsoleSpanExporter(),
  instrumentations: [getNodeAutoInstrumentations()]
});

sdk.start()
```

As well as the customized `tracing.js` for jaeger:

```
const process = require('process');
const opentelemetry = require('@opentelemetry/sdk-node');
const {
  getNodeAutoInstrumentations,
} = require('@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node');
const { Resource } = require('@opentelemetry/resources');
const {
  SemanticResourceAttributes,
} = require('@opentelemetry/semantic-conventions');
const { JaegerExporter } = require('@opentelemetry/exporter-jaeger');

const hostName = process.env.OTEL_TRACE_HOST || 'localhost';

const options = {
  tags: [],
  endpoint: `http://${hostName}:1234/api/traces`,
};
const traceExporter = new JaegerExporter(options);

// configure the SDK to export telemetry data to the console
// enable all auto-instrumentations from the meta package
const sdk = new opentelemetry.NodeSDK({
  resource: new Resource({
    [SemanticResourceAttributes.SERVICE_NAME]: 'my_app',
  }),
  traceExporter,
  instrumentations: [
    getNodeAutoInstrumentations({
      // Each of the auto-instrumentations
      // can have config set here or you can
      // npm install each individually and not use the auto-instruments
      '@opentelemetry/instrumentation-http': {
        ignoreIncomingPaths: [
          // Pattern match to filter endpoints
          // that you really want to stop altogether
          '/ping',

          // You can filter conditionally
          // Next.js gets a little too chatty
          // if you trace all the incoming requests
          ...(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
            ? [/^\/_next\/static.*/]
            : []),
        ],

        // This gives your request spans a more meaningful name
        // than `HTTP GET`
        requestHook: (span, request) => {
          span.setAttributes({
            name: `${request.method} ${request.url || request.path}`,
          });
        },

        // Re-assign the root span's attributes
        startIncomingSpanHook: (request) => {
          return {
            name: `${request.method} ${request.url || request.path}`,
            'request.path': request.url || request.path,
          };
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
});

// initialize the SDK and register with the OpenTelemetry API
// this enables the API to record telemetry
sdk
  .start()
  .then(() => console.log('Tracing initialized'))
  .catch((error) =>
    console.log('Error initializing tracing and starting server', error)
  );

// gracefully shut down the SDK on process exit
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  sdk
    .shutdown()
    .then(() => console.log('Tracing terminated'))
    .catch((error) => console.log('Error terminating tracing', error))
    .finally(() => process.exit(0));
});
```

---

Separately, building and then serving does not speed up the load times either.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you were experiencing the issue that was reported here [[@opentelemetry/instrumentation] require performance grows linearly with each instrumentation plugin](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js/issues/3029). Within this issue, there was a bug that caused instrumentation to be layered on top of itself repeatedly. They have since fixed the issue.

See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75081482/3195089).