# Adding opentelemetry tracing to Node.js app breaks `require("fs").realpathSync.native`

Tags: javascript, node.js, trace, open-telemetry

Using the following tracing enabling script from [OpenTelemetry docs](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/js/getting-started/nodejs/):

```js
const opentelemetry = require("@opentelemetry/sdk-node");
const { getNodeAutoInstrumentations } = require("@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node");
const { diag, DiagConsoleLogger, DiagLogLevel } = require('@opentelemetry/api');

// For troubleshooting, set the log level to DiagLogLevel.DEBUG
diag.setLogger(new DiagConsoleLogger(), DiagLogLevel.INFO);

const sdk = new opentelemetry.NodeSDK({
  traceExporter: new opentelemetry.tracing.ConsoleSpanExporter(),
  instrumentations: [getNodeAutoInstrumentations()]
});

sdk.start()
```

running my Next.js server as I thought is required, I get an error:

```bash
$ node --require './tracing/opentelemetry.js' ./node_modules/next/dist/bin/next start -p 3000
No modules instrumentation has been defined, nothing will be patched
@opentelemetry/instrumentation-grpc Module @grpc/grpc-js has been loaded before @opentelemetry/instrumentation-grpc so it might not work, please initialize it before requiring @grpc/grpc-js
Exporter "otlp" requested through environment variable is unavailable.
/mnt/vol/.local/share/pnpm/global/5/.pnpm/next@12.1.5_zpnidt7m3osuk7shl3s4oenomq/node_modules/next/dist/lib/get-project-dir.js:40
        const realDir = _fs.default.realpathSync.native(resolvedDir);
                                                 ^

TypeError: _fs.default.realpathSync.native is not a function
    at Object.getProjectDir (/mnt/vol/.local/share/pnpm/global/5/.pnpm/next@12.1.5_zpnidt7m3osuk7shl3s4oenomq/node_modules/next/dist/lib/get-project-dir.js:40:50)
    at nextStart (/mnt/vol/.local/share/pnpm/global/5/.pnpm/next@12.1.5_zpnidt7m3osuk7shl3s4oenomq/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-start.js:80:37)
    at /mnt/vol/.local/share/pnpm/global/5/.pnpm/next@12.1.5_zpnidt7m3osuk7shl3s4oenomq/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next:141:34
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

Node.js v17.8.0
```

Now this can be simplified to a minimal reproduction as follows. This has the `fs.realpathSync.native` function:

```bash
$ node -e 'console.log(require("fs").realpathSync)'
[Function: realpathSync] { native: [Function (anonymous)] }
```

This doesn't have `fs.realpathSync.native`:

```bash
$ node --require ./tracing/opentelemetry.js -e 'console.log(require("fs").realpathSync)'
No modules instrumentation has been defined, nothing will be patched
@opentelemetry/instrumentation-grpc Module @grpc/grpc-js has been loaded before @opentelemetry/instrumentation-grpc so it might not work, please initialize it before requiring @grpc/grpc-js
[Function (anonymous)]
Exporter "otlp" requested through environment variable is unavailable.
```

My Node's `--require` is working correctly (`noop.js` is an empty file):

```bash
$ node --require ./tracing/noop.js -e 'console.log(require("fs").realpathSync)'
[Function: realpathSync] { native: [Function (anonymous)] }
```

Why would the OpenTelemetry setup script break the `fs` module?

```bash
$ node --version
v17.8.0
```

```json
//package.json dependencies
    "@opentelemetry/api": "^1.3.0",
    "@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node": "^0.35.0",
    "@opentelemetry/sdk-node": "^0.34.0",
```

```bash
$ uname -a
Linux code-server 5.15.0-1025-oracle #31~20.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 29 13:01:56 UTC 2022 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Does my ARM machine have something to do with it?

I can reproduce the same on x86_64 on https://replit.com/@JakubKoralewski/opentelemetry-repro with the same behavior.

Comment: I have the exact same issue with next.js version 12.3.4. Any solutions?

Comment: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js-contrib/pull/1332 I was trying to fix it but dont have time to respond to review

Comment: @sebascomeau I think downgrading opentelemetry to 0.33 version fixed it btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this error occurs is due to a bug in `@opentelemetry/instrumentation-fs` introduced as a new dependency to `@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node` in [PR #981](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js-contrib/pull/981) which got released with version `0.34.0`. [The issue](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js-contrib/issues/1315) was reported but at the time of writing is still open. However, as also already linked above [a PR to address the issue](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js-contrib/pull/1332) is being reviewed.

Fow now, I see three ways to address the problem:

1. As suggested in a comment above downgrade `@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node` to next lower version `0.33.1`.
2. Disable the file system instrumentation when configuring the node instrumentation. For that simply replace `getNodeAutoInstrumentations()` with `getNodeAutoInstrumentations({ '@opentelemetry/instrumentation-fs': { enabled: false } })` in your code. Given that your project is in Next.js and you likely have little file system activity aside from maybe public files this is likely the best option for now.
3. Remove `@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node` altogether and simply instrument the libraries you actually use. Using the auto instrumentation for Node.js pulls in [a lot of transitive dependencies](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js-contrib/blob/main/metapackages/auto-instrumentations-node/package.json#L48-L86). Say you have a Next.js app, connect to a Postgres database and use winston for logging your instrumentation setup could look something like this:

```js
const sdk = new opentelemetry.NodeSDK({
  traceExporter: new opentelemetry.tracing.ConsoleSpanExporter(),
  instrumentations: [
    // new FsInstrumentation(), TODO: re-enable once bug is fixed
    new HttpInstrumentation(),
    new PgInstrumentation(),
    new WinstonInstrumentation(),
  ]
});
```